# Select multiple result by grouping same values from single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am creating an email alert to send out three email separately from the below table:

```
|**ID** |**Name**      |**Company**    |**Count**|            
|1      |John          |Apple          |2        |
|2      |Bill          |Microsoft      |2        |
|3      |Steve         |Apple          |2        |
|4      |Elon          |Tesla          |1        |
|5      |Satya         |Microsoft      |2        |
```

I desire to get all three different result to send the email separately

```
|**ID** |**Name**      |**Company**    |   
|1      |John          |Apple          |   
|3      |Steve         |Apple          |

AND 

|**ID** |**Name**      |**Company**    |
|2      |Bill          |Microsoft      |
|5      |Satya         |Microsoft      |

AND

|**ID** |**Name**      |**Company**    |
|4      |Elon          |Tesla          |
```

How could I get the desired result as above in SQL?

Comment: execute 3 different queries or `order by company` and play with the company name while fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM your_table ORDER BY Company;

Answer (score 0):

This query will help you:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE COMPANY="company_name"
```

just replace `company_name` by Apple, Microsoft, or Tesla.

Comment: that is just an example name. I am doing an auto email notify feature which the data will not SELECT by me but the query itself. When there are new records in the table, the email will send out sorting by company, I could not ensure what is the name of the company.